# Cannot install react navigation ({react native})

Tags: react-native

Cannot install react navigation, error is as below,

```
   F:\Test2>npm install --save react-navigation
    npm WARN @babel/plugin-check-constants@7.0.0-beta.38 requires a peer of @babel/core@7.0.0-beta.38 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN react-native-screens@1.0.0-alpha.9 requires a peer of react@16.0.0-alpha.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN react-native-screens@1.0.0-alpha.9 requires a peer of react-native@^0.44.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'F:\Test2\node_modules\.staging\fsevents-db169078\node_modules\nopt' -> 'F:\Test2\node_modules\.staging\nopt-ec00ee2d'

    npm ERR! path F:\Test2\node_modules\hoist-non-react-statics
    npm ERR! code ENOENT
    npm ERR! errno -4058
    npm ERR! syscall rename
    npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'F:\Test2\node_modules\hoist-non-react-statics' -> 'F:\Test2\node_modules\.hoist-non-react-statics.DELETE'
    npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
    npm ERR! enoent

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\usman\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09-13T04_40_04_090Z-debug.log
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: anyhelp would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

First try

```
npm install -g react-navigation
```

Or next :

Try installing

```
npm install @react-navigation/native
```

First take a backup of all the dependencies in node modules.

Take information about `package.json`
with this file u can able to know which dependcies are already install if require u can reinstall npm then again do `npm install@react-navigation/native`

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `hoist-non-react-statics` package is incorrect. So you could re-install it or re-install the whole `node_modules`.

First of all, backup your `node_modules` folder. This is very important!
Then delete `node_modules` folder and re-install the npm packages with `npm install`.

After above operation, try installing `react-navigation` again.